Is there any study of the temperature gradient at the surface of a liquid?
My tiny brain expects liquids to be cooler at the surface due to evaporation. However, I couldn't find any experimental evidence for it.
Is there any study of the temperature gradient at the surface of a liquid?

I’m not aware of any studies or experiments (have you done any research?), but it is logical that the temperature would be lower at the surface.
Temperature is a measure of the average kinetic energy of the molecules of the liquid. The kinetic energy of individual molecules varies about that average. At the surface the molecules having higher kinetic energy have the opportunity to escape the liquid whereas they don’t below the surface. That results in lowering the average kinetic energy of the remaining molecules near the surface and thus the temperature.
Hope this helps.

Thank you, upvoted for your informative opinion. However, my main question was whether there is any experimental evidence that this happens. As mentioned in the question, I have tried to search for it but couldn't find it.
